# Handling Single Table Inheritance with a different column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

I have the following tables

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product_type
 self.inheritance_column = :product_type_id
end

class MotorProduct < Product
end

class CarProduct < Product
end
```

I also have this record in my db

```
Product table records
    #<Product id: 1, product_type_id: 1, company_id: 36, name: "Text Motor Insurancee">

Product Type table records
#<ProductType id: 1, name: "Motor">
#<ProductType id: 2, name: "Car">
```

When i do MotorProduct.all, it returns empty. This is what my query runs

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."product_type_id" IN (0)
```

which means it wasn't able to map properly the product type id.Not sure how to map it out but basically when i run `MotorProduct.all`, i am expecting my query to be

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."product_type_id" IN (1).
```

I know i can easily solve all of this if i add a column called `type` and give type the same name `MotorProduct` but since the current code had this structure, i am trying to see if i can maintain it somehow.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to (also) have an attribute that contains the String name. Ik guess you could do both at the same time though. Keep the relationship as is, but also add a new attribute `product_type-name` that contains the same name as the relationship to use for STI. You could even consider populating it in a `before_save` callback

Comment: I'm just wondering though, what's the use case for setting this up as STI? What is the benefit of having a separate class for Motor products and Car products? You could create scopes for that right? `Product.motor_products` or `Product.car_products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inheritance_column` is [supposed to contain class names](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/943beb1ea23866d46922a5c850f79a0fb9531f9b/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L6-L30), not arbitrary integers (emphasis mine):

> Active Record allows inheritance by storing the **name of the class** in a column that by default is named "type" (can be changed by overwriting `Base.inheritance_column`).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the rights docs, but the `inheritance_column` has to be a string column, not an integer. Internally the content of that field is used to determine the class to instantiate the object with.

Comment: yes, but still, it doesn't say what type to db field has to be. For an absolute beginner that might be hard to know.